# How do I render a template form inside another template. Python, Flask, Jinja2

Tags: python, html, templates, flask, jinja2

Just studied a Python course and I'm attempting my first step to try something on my own (just so you know my experience level).

I have a very basic social app that when an admin logs in, it takes them to admin.html which extends layout.html.

On this admin page, I would like to include/render another template, which has a form to add things to a database. Kind of like a template form inside of another template. Only problem is, that I keep getting an error and I've tried a few things to fix it, but I'm stuck. Below is the parts of code that I think are relevant to the problem and the error trace.

Hoping someone can explain in basic terms where I'm going wrong.

admin.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %} 

{% block content %}
    <h1>Welcome to the admin page!</h1>
    {% include 'standards.html' %}
{% endblock content %}
```

standards.html

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %} 
{% from 'macros.html' import render_field %} 

{% block content %}
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }} 
        {% for field in form %} 
            {{ render_field(field) }} 
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Add Standard</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

app.py

```
@app.route('/login', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def login():
    form = forms.LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            user = models.User.get(models.User.email == form.email.data)
        except models.DoesNotExist:
            flash("Your email or password doesn't match!", "error")
        else:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
                login_user(user)
                if (user.is_admin == 1):
                    return redirect(url_for('admin'))
                else:
                    flash("You've been logged in!", "success")
                return redirect(url_for('index'))
            else:
                flash("Your email or password doesn't match!", "error")
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)


@app.route('/admin', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def admin():
    if (models.User.is_admin == True):
        return render_template('admin.html')
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))


@app.route('/add_standard', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def set_standard():
    form = forms.StandardForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        models.Standards.create_standard(
            section=form.section.data,
            standard=form.standard.data
        )
        flash("Standard created! Thanks!", "success")
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('standards.html', form=form)
```

models.py

```
class Standards(Model):
    section = CharField(unique=False)
    standard = CharField(unique=True)
    
    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE
        
    
    @classmethod
    def create_standard(cls, section, standard):
        try:
            with DATABASE.transaction():
                cls.create(
                    section=section,
                    standard=standard
                )
        except IntegrityError:
            raise ValueError("Standard already exists")
```

forms.py

```
class StandardForm(FlaskForm):
    section = TextAreaField('Set section title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    standard = TextAreaField('Enter the standard to be added', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

error trace

```
File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner-driver-app\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2091, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner-driver-app\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner-driver-app\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner-driver-app\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner-driver-app\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner-driver-app\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner-driver-app\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 272, in decorated_view
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner-driver-app\app.py", line 109, in admin
return render_template('admin.html')
File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner-driver-app\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 147, in render_template
return _render(
File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner-driver-app\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 128, in _render
rv = template.render(context)
File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner-driver-app\venv\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1291, in render
self.environment.handle_exception()
File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner-driver-app\venv\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 925, in handle_exception
raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner-driver-app\templates\admin.html", line 1, in top-level template code
{% extends 'layout.html' %} {% block content %}
File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner-driver-app\templates\layout.html", line 70, in top-level template code
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner-driver-app\templates\admin.html", line 3, in block 'content'
{% include 'standards.html' %}{% endblock content %}
File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner-driver-app\templates\standards.html", line 1, in top-level template code
{% extends "layout.html" %} {% from 'macros.html' import render_field %} {% block content %}
File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner-driver-app\templates\layout.html", line 70, in top-level template code
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner-driver-app\templates\standards.html", line 3, in block 'content'
{{ form.hidden_tag() }} {% for field in form %} {{ render_field(field) }} {% endfor %}
File "D:\Dropbox\Coding Projects\learner-driver-app\venv\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 474, in getattr
return getattr(obj, attribute)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined
```

Comment: Update: I've tried to use an include statement instead of the url_for, and now it throws the error message. Cannot find standards.html in templates. However, it is most definitely there and correctly spelled. I've tried it by using both with and without 'templates/' file path. It still does not find the file.

Comment: the `form` variable that you're using in `standards.html`, need to passed as an input.

Comment: @NavaneethaKrishnan - How do you mean? Where do you think the form variable would need to go? The form reference in standards.html is just html.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. The reference to 'form undefined' is actually referring to the admin view function. Because I'm passing through 'standards.html' which has a form inside it, I need to also tell the admin view function that at some point, it will get passed a form. Even though the admin view itself does not use a form.

So from my original code, the new code looks like so:

```
@app.route('/admin')
@login_required
def admin():
    form = forms.StandardForm()
    if (models.User.is_admin == True):
        return render_template('admin.html', form=form)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

and in my admin.html template, I just use:

```
{% include 'standards.html' %}
```

Now it works fine! Thanks guys for the support! :)